# Setting variable from inside directive

Tags: angularjs

How can I set position from inside the directive?

**Page controller:**

```
$scope.position = 0;
```

Chart directive in page:

```
<chart></chart>
```

Inside the chart directive I do some work on the position

```
angular.module('app')
       .directive('chart',

function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            chartData: '=',
            position: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
          var position = 10; // Need to set position so parent controller's position is updated
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to to pass `position` variable to your directive.

```
<chart position="position"></chart>
```

Then in your `link` function, you can access to your position variable using `scope`

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 

   scope.position = your_value;

}
```